# How do I convert a LocalDateTime to a JavaScript Date object with JS-Joda?

Tags: javascript, date, jodatime, js-joda

how do I convert a LocalDateTime Object from the @js-joda/core library to a standard JavaScript Date object?

Comment: It's [in the documentation](https://js-joda.github.io/js-joda/manual/convert-native.html): `let date = convert(ZonedDateTime.now()).toDate();`. BTW, the documentation has inaccuracies: "*The native Date object always consist of a date, time and a timezone part.*" which is incorrect. ECMAScript dates are **only** a millisecond offset from the epoch. Dates and times are calculated from the offset, timezone information comes from the host.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @RobG mentioned in a comment import convert from '@js-joda/core' and you can use  `let date = convert(ZonedDateTime.now()).toDate();` to get a js date